# Zebra ZPL control length of void line

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I am trying to control voided label and so far I am able to control it with regards to y-axis by using `^RS` code (i.e., # of lines, height of line or its position on y axis).

I wonder if there is anything similar to control void on x-axis? Like printing only 2 voids at the center of a label so far, I only find information that it prints void across line.

I tried controlling that by field, but no luck so far

```
^FO100,100^FB100,4
^FD
^RS,F10,7,1^FS
```